# Custom pinned document order in Office

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

Whenever I pin a document in Office 2013’s “open file” tab, it puts them in alphabetical order. While this is useful, it separates groups of files I use for different tasks all over the list. Is there a way to reorder them myself short of changing the file names and repinning the entire list?

Comment: How would you expect it to sort them?  How would it know which files you want grouped together?

Comment: I'm looking to group and/or reorder them manually.